# KMeans data treatment

Tags: pca, k-means, categorical-encoding

I have a dataset with a set of features regarding:

```
Age  Country  TypeA1 TypeB1 TypeC1
```

Where Country is a feature that can have 195 different potential values, TypeA1 can have 50 different potential values, TypeB1 can have 32 potential values and TypeC1 can have 42 potential values.

I would like to compute clusters by using Kmeans algorithm.

My concern here is that, if I use the whole set of potential values within each variable in dummies the number of columns could have too much and the risk would be dispersion.

How I should treat the variables?
By using dummies, or by using categorical (encoding the label with a number) and then performing the dimensionality reduction (eg PCA) before training the Kmeans?

Comment: If these variables are categorical then it would be erroneous to treat them as continuous. Can you group these categorical variables into classes, for ex. Europe, Asia and so on instead of countries? To decrease the dimensionality of the data.

Comment: Also, K-means and similar work on continuous data, as they need to compute distances, which are not really meaningful for categorical variables. You may try Gower's distance or something, but if you have all categorical variables you might want to change your approach,

Comment: I cannot group them into classes. What do you think about the method "KPrototypes" for mixed data types? Moreover, if I use continuos labels for the categorical variables and then PCA, may it work?